# Calculate the dot product when for one of the vectors we only know the sum

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, number-theory

The problem is to calculate the following quantity:

$$ax+by$$

I know $a, b \in [0, 1]$, $x, y\in \mathbb Z^+$, and I know the sum of $x$ and $y$. Is it possible to calculate $ax+by$?

I have tried using substitution of one variable, trying notable products like $(a+b)(x+y)$, etc., with no luck.

Comment: Not in general. Suppose for example that $a=1$ and $b=0$. Then $ax + by = x$, which obviously cannot be uniquely identified given only $x+y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ is the sum of $x$ and $y$, then we know $x=t,y=S-t$ for some $t$. Then your dot product is:

$$at+b(S-t)=(a-b)t+bS$$

and clearly, except when $a=b$, by choosing the right value of $t$ we can get this to equal any number. So we cannot say anything at all about this dot product.

If $a=b$ then we can calculate the dot product since it's just $a(x+y)=aS$.